# Aligning button addons input with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form with 2 inputs, Text input and a button to submit the form.

Next to this form there is text at the left.

I want to align that text at the left with the text input field.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5vdcb120/1

CSS code:

```
.text, .form{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <p class="text">Name:</p>
  <form class="wrapper">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>        
    </div> <!-- .input-group -->
    <p>Some Text</p>
  <form> <!-- .form-->
</div> <!-- .container -->
```

I want to align the text `Name:` with `text` class with the text input, To be at the middle of the text input.

I tried `vertical-alignment: middle;`, But it didn't work.

[image: Images]

Comment: Use display: flex property, u can do this alignment easily

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure i understood your question but hopefully this helps: https://jsfiddle.net/aoc3g96d/5/

```css
 .text, 
 .form{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.text {
 top: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 
 width: 9%;
 text-align: right;
}

.form {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
<p class="text">Name:</p>
 <form class="form">
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" placeholder="SomeText" class="form-control">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button>
   </span>
  </div>
 <form>
</div>
```

Comment: That's how it should look like, But I don't like to use that `top` method

Comment: you could maybe use line-height instead, just out of curiosity why don't you like to use top

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
 display: flex; 
 align-items: baseline;
```

to the container class to make to work for you like that.

Good luck with the coding!

```css
.text, .form{
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">

  <p class="text">Name: </p>
  <form class="wrapper">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    </form>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with CSS Grid Property to container class:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0px 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">

  <p class="text">Name: </p>
  <form class="wrapper">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    </form>
    
</div>
```